# Is there any way to crop a video automatically in android studio?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-videoview

What I want to do is receive a video in a videoView, for example, stored in firebase. And I need that video to fit a vertical videoView, cutting off or not showing any excess. So if its an horizontal video just remove the sides and center it.  Something like this : [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rn3fZ.png)

Comment: Are you expecting player or cropper? Cropper means every device have different density.

Comment: either is fine. just what allows me to achieve that result.  But regarding what you said maybe player would be better.

Comment: Check Google exo player...